# NSOperation Fetching Image and Updating UITableView UIImageView Property

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have created a fetchImageOperation class which inherits from NSOperation. It fetches the image using a URL and then fires the block when done. My question is that if I have the following code:

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    Customer *customer = [_customers objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    FetchImageOperation *imageOperation = [[FetchImageOperation alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:vegetable.imageURL]];

    cell.nameLabel.text = customer.name;

    imageOperation.fetchImageOperationCompletionBlock = ^(UIImage *image)
    {
        [cell.thumbnailImageView setImage:image];
    };

    [_queue addOperation:imageOperation];

    return cell;
}
```

Is the setImage method called on the main thread (UI Thread) by default? I can confirm that the above code works and it does sets the image property of the thumbnailaImageView element.

**FetchImageOperation.m file:**

```
@implementation FetchImageOperation

-(id) initWithURL:(NSURL *)url
{
    self = [super init];
    self.url = url;
    return self;
}


-(void) main
{
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:_url];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

    if(self.fetchImageOperationCompletionBlock != nil)
    {
        self.fetchImageOperationCompletionBlock(image);
    }
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In no way is the call to any UI method automatically on the main thread. In this case, it will be called on whatever thread your `NSOperation` subclass's `main` method is running on.

You should use something like

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    if(self.fetchImageOperationCompletionBlock != nil) {
        self.fetchImageOperationCompletionBlock(image);
    }
});
```

If you want to guarantee all the `fetchImageOperationCompletionBlock`s are fired on the main thread. And due to cell re-use you'll want to not be calling properties on the cell itself, instead save the index path to the cell in the block and and use the cell at that index path, or something.

Answer (score 0):

The block is called on the same thread as the operation. So no, it's called on a background thread, so it won't work properly.

Also, when the block finishes you have no idea if the cell is still being used for the same thing or if its been reused.

Rather than doing what you're doing, look at using something like `SDWebImage`.

Answer (score 0):

You could save the cell's indexPaths and FetchImageOperation in the dictionary to be able to control the operation progress and cell access after the application completes:

```
NSMutableDictionary *operations; // Define and initialise dictionary to hold operations   

- (void)(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // ...

    UIImage *image = [customer image];
    if (image == nil) {
        image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ImageHolder"];
        if (![[operations allKeys] containsObject:indexPath]) {
            FetchImageOperation *imageOperation = [[FetchImageOperation alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:vegetable.imageURL]];
            imageOperation.fetchImageOperationCompletionBlock = ^(UIImage *image) {
                // Do updates on the main thread
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]
                    [cell.thumbnailImageView setImage:image];
                    [operations removeObjectForKey:indexPath];
                };
            };
            [operations setObject:imageOperation forKey:indexPath];
            [_queue addOperation:imageOperation];
        }
    }
}

// You should cancel image operations if cell goes out from the screen
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didEndDisplayingCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSOperation *operation = [operations objectForKey:indexPath];
    [operation cancel];
}
```